# Why are men not told to cover from head to toe in a thick outer garment?

Tags: women, hijab, men, equality

Women are told to cover their bodies properly with a loose and thick outer garment (hijab). However men are only told to cover a section of their body. I understand that one should guard their private parts and so cover them however, women also have to cover their hair, neck, arms and legs where as men do not have to cover these parts. Both men and women have the tendency to look at the opposite gender, not just men.

A man only had to cover from the navel to the knee. The rest of his body can be left bare.

Women have to cover because men feel attracted to women by just looking at them. But this goes both ways as women can also be attracted to men by just looking. Also although it is haram to be gay, we cannot deny that there is a rise in gay men and so shouldn't men too cover themselves as some men feel attracted towards them too?

Comment: Are women told to cover with a thick outer garment?

Comment: @Medi1Saif yes because the body shouldn't be seen. This means the garment should not be thin as this will be see-though and it should not be tight as it will still show the shape of the body. So it should be loose, thick and long to cover the whole body.

Comment: Under thick I was expecting a thick or lined coat.

Comment: @Medi1Saif No it just has to be thick enough so the shape of the body is not know.

Comment: Maybe helpful http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28607/is-man-torso-chest-trunk-awrah/28614?s=1|3.8157#28614

Answer (score -4):

Asalamu Alaikum, 
      First of all, man was created first by ALLAH before a woman.. As you might know the woman referred to as "the crooked rib" was created from the mans ribs thereby making him stronger than her. Men have the ability to withstand better than women... The Man is vulnerable when it comes to the woman. The woman when created by ALLAH was adorned with various beauties... Her face is enough to cause havoc to the male gender.... She Is a beautiful flower and as such flowers should be preserved and she is also the one who can melt the man as you know that Hauwa was weak and easily deceived by shaytan and also it was she who convinced Adam to eat the forbidden fruit.... Females should cover to protect themselves from the desires of the male... Covering up reduces things such as rape and fornication... 
      Lastly, since ALLAH has ordered the female to cover up, who are we to go against his commands... He is the most merciful and he is the knower of the unknown.... Allah knows best.

Comment: Please revise your answer as suggested [here: How to answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer)