# Correct Hijab For Men vs Women

Tags: women, hijab, men, awrah

We often see the hijab for women being addressed by scholars as well as other people e.g. post on social media point out the correct and incorrect hijab.

Unfortunately, the same attention is not given when it come to the j=hijab for men.

I understand that the hijab's purpose is to cover the 'awrah' which for a female is considered to be head to toe except her hands, face and feet. Now, the awrah for men considerably less as it only includes a section of the body which is from the navel to the knee.

My question is that why are we always told that women are not wearing the correct hijab because hijab does not only mean to cover the hair, but it also means to cover the entire body with a THICK, LOOSE FITTING garment which does not show the shape of the body such as an abaya or jilbab.

However, the material and shape of clothing for men is never spoken of. Shouldn't men also have to wear a thick and loose fitting garment even if it is just from navel to knee. As the shape of that area too should not be shown as it is considered the awrah? So this should mean jeans, trousers, jogging bottoms etc should not be worn in-front of non mahrams just like women should not wear short or tight clothes?

Now even the Qur'an does not say word for word that women should wear hijab but rather that the women of Ansar covered their chests and it was the norm to cover their hair at the time. The Qur'an does however say we should follow the examples of the Prophet (saw) and we know that he always wore loose long garments (thawbs) so shouldn't this be how Muslim men should  really cover all the time not just Friday prayer?

Comment: I'm afraid this question might be considered as opinion-based. One may answer it because almost all scholars and authorities are male. But in fact most fatwa-questions about hijab come from men (husbands, fiancées) and also from women, while the question about what a man should or shouldn't wear come IMO in first place from interested or curiouse men only and there are in content as many as there are about the female hijab!

Comment: I would recommend you to re-phrase your question asking what is the correct appearance for a men infornt of non-mahram's! Note that thick clothes for women's hijab is only an interpretation for not being transparent I don't think that Allah wants his female servants to get dead in the heat of summer due to their clothing!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are men not told to cover from head to toe in a thick outer garment?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31009/why-are-men-not-told-to-cover-from-head-to-toe-in-a-thick-outer-garment)

Comment: Why do you keep closing questions because you can't answer them or there is no answer maybe? I'm not asking for opinions I am asking why the ruling are like that so answers should be based on authentic hadiths and verses of the Quran!!