# Would it be allowed for men to walk without covering the torso from the belly buttom upwards?

Tags: muslim-practices, clothing

Let's say it is 40 degrees Celsius (104 degrees Fahrenheit and 313 degrees Kelvin) or warmer would you be allowed to walk publicly without covering the torso from the belly buttom upwards, but you'll still be covering your awrah ( the area from the knees till the bell buttom(belly buttom included))?

Comment: According to [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28607/is-man-torso-chest-trunk-awrah) answer it is permissible because I think it is needed in times of warm weather.

Comment: So do you consider this a duplicate or not? In other words Is your question answered there or not?

Comment: Well yeah, I'll delete it.

Comment: Keep it as a duplicate

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll do that.

Comment: Can you mark it as such? The idea is if anyone had the same question in mind he would easily recognize it as a duplicate and might profit from an answer.

Comment: Ok,I've done that.

Comment: In my opinion, whether allowed or not, covering your body wholly protects you better from the hot and harmful sunlight. Also, I know that chest of men may create desire in women (or men), and may cause hardship, so, my preference is to always cover, regardless of how hot it is.